# Memory management of chained CompletableFutures

Tags: java, asynchronous, memory-management, garbage-collection, completable-future

I am writing an async client. Each time a request is sent, the client creates, registers internally, then returns a `CompletableFuture`, that will be completed once the server's response to the send request is received.

The problem is, some requests never receive a response, and the client code gives up on them after some timeout. And so, I end up with multiple registered `CompletableFuture`s that the client code no longer hold reference to, and as such should be eligible to garbage collection.

In order to avoid memory leaks, I decided to change the implementation of my client to maintain `WeakReference`s to the returned `CompletableFuture`s instead of a strong ones, so that the non-referenced futures get's evicted if client code doesn't need them anymore.

The following (simplified) code demonstrates the client:

```
interface Message {
    Object getID();
    byte[] toByteArray();
}

abstract class AsyncClient<T extends Message, R extends Message> {
    /**
     * This map serves as a registry of CompletableFutures for sent requests.
     * 
     * Previously it was Map<Object, CompletableFuture<R>>. Changed to References
     * to avoid CompletableFutures staying in registry after the recipient code
     * does not wait for them anymore.
     */
    Map<Object, Reference<CompletableFuture<R>>> requestFutureRegistry = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    /**
     * Write the request to the service
     * @param serializedRequest bytes to write
     */
    protected abstract void writeRequest(byte[] serializedRequest);

    /**
     * Make sure to clean up the registry from Futures that arte not held by the 
     * recipient code anymore.
     */
    private void deleteDanglingFutures() {
        requestFutureRegistry.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue().get() == null);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param request to be written to service
     * @return a CompletableFuture for the request's response
     */
    public CompletableFuture<R> sendRequest(T request) {
        deleteDanglingFutures();

        CompletableFuture<R> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        requestFutureRegistry.put(request.getID(), new WeakReference<>(future));

        writeRequest(request.toByteArray());

        return future;
    }

    void receivedResponse(R response) {
        deleteDanglingFutures();

        Reference<CompletableFuture<R>> futureRef = requestFutureRegistry.get(response.getID());
        if (futureRef != null) {
            CompletableFuture<R> future = futureRef.get();
            if (future != null) {
                future.complete(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach seemed to work, until I started to chain `CompletableFuture`s using thenXXX methods. for instance, when I did things like the following:

```
AsyncClient client;
Request request1;
// ...

Response response = client.sendRequest(request1)
                          .thenCompose(response1 -> 
                                       client.sendRequest(request2)
                           ).get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I noticed the internal future (from the call to `client.sendRequest(request2)`) getting sometimes GC'd before it gets the chance to be completed.

Digging a bit more into the JDK implementation, it seems that no strong reference is stored to internal future (as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530286/non-intuitive-object-eviction-from-garbage-collection)).

My question is - what would be the correct way to make sure that registered futures are evicted if client code doesn't reference them anymore (directly or via thenXXX chaining), and yet stick around long enough for completion in case they are still needed?

**EDIT + motivation**

I understand now (thanks @Holger) that `Future::get` is not the common usage of `CompletableFuture`s, However, it is very common in my case. Specifically, one use case I need to support is sending multiple requests, waiting for the first one to respond (using `anyOf` and then `get` with timeout). It is known in advance that many of the requests will never get response from the service, so I need to (preferably automatically) clean up unused futures after timeout.

Comment: What precisely do you mean with “registered futures”? I’m not sure whether I understood your scenario correctly, but when someone gives up after a timeout, it should complete the future exceptionally or at least, stop holding a reference to it when it knows that it is never going to complete it. Then, it shouldn’t need weak references at all.

Comment: @Holger, I hope that the code snippets I added helps to better understand the question.

Comment: But when do you decide that no response will happen, i.e. a timeout occurred?

Comment: If the code calling `sendRequest` is not referencing the CompletableFuture, then I do not need to complete it anymore (since no one will `get()` the response). So, even if a response is received from the service at a later time, it can be ignored (or maybe just logged).

Comment: There is a logical flaw in your reasoning. If I call `sendRequest(xyz).thenAccept(System.out::println)`, I don’t need to keep a reference to the future to make the subsequent action valid. I simply don’t need to call `get`, in fact, calling `get()` is atypical for `CompletableFuture`. Keeping a reference to a future or not, surely is not the right way to tell another component whether to await a response or not. Just add something like `cancelRequest(T request) { requestFutureRegistry.remove(request.getID()); }`…

Comment: OK, fair point. What if I do `future.whenComplete((response, t) -> requestFutureRegistry.remove(request.getID()));` before returning it, and require the user to cancel the future? would that work? and - can I automatically detect timeout on a `future.get()` call and cancel it and its dependent futures?

Comment: The problem is that when you do `initialRequest().then…().then…()`, you’ll get a future representing the last stage of the chain and when cancelling that future, you’re *only* cancelling that stage, i.e. the future returned by `initialRequest()` is not affected. It’s the same issue as with your weak reference approach; you need callers being aware of the different future identities. How about adding a timeout parameter right to `sendRequest(…)` instead? That simplifies everything.

Comment: Actually, `sendRequest` timeout is an interesting approach as long as I don't make the API blocking (maybe add expiration time into the registry and clean up old request completing them with `TimeoutException`). I will look into it, thanks.